# Rank calculation using variables working only sometimes

Tags: mysql, mariadb, order-by

I have the following code in MariaDB that was working perfectly well yesterday. It calculates a rank and orders by the data by another column:

```
SET @c = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable);
SET @rownum = 0;
UPDATE myTable
SET rank = (100 / @c) * (@rownum:= 1 + @rownum)
ORDER BY anotherColumn DESC LIMIT 100000;
```

Today I executed it and the first time through it gave the wrong ranking values. I don't think the `SET @rownum = 0` had worked. Now it seems to be working fine again.

Does anyone know why it would work perfectly yesterday and then stop working today and behave so strangely?

I believe the `@c` is the variable that isn't updating when I add a new row. Does anyone know how to force it to recalculate `@c` based on the current data in the table?

I don't think the connection dropped out because I created the new row immediately after using HeidiSQL. I don't understand how it can even use an old value. If that was JavaScript, you would just get an error.

I'm using MariaDB version 5.2

Comment: Not the clearest clearest description however `SET @c`  `SET @rownum` are session specific and not global so it might have dropped connection before the `UPDATE` was run. Note that this might be easier written as a [window frame](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/window-frames/) that has [rank](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/rank/) and [row_number](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/row_number/) window functions. What wrong ranking values did you have?

Answer (score 1):

MariaDB 5.2 is really old.  Upgrade.

MariaDB 10.2 (and MySQL 8.0) have `RANK` and other "windowing functions" to assist with your query.

Setting @variables inside `SELECTs` should *not* be trusted.  Rewrite the query to avoid them.

Updating everyone's rank all the time will be a performance drag when you have a lot of users.